# Similarities and differences among Internal Family Systems, Shadow Work, and Schema Therapy

Tags: cognitive-psychology, abnormal-psychology, therapy, jung

I'm interested in knowing more about Internal Family Systems, Shadow Work, and Schema Therapy, in relation to each other. All 3 appear to provide a way to become a more integrated person.

I have 4 questions about these, which could fill a book, so I will ask each in its own post.

First question: What are the similarities and differences among them?